# Easiest way to dynamically get/set properties of c# objects by name

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I have several objects of different types and the name of a property that I need to get and set on these. In languages like javascript this is trivial as I can get and set values with indexor syntax.

```
obj2[propertyName] = obj1[propertyName];
```

In c# it's not so easy. I know I can use reflection but that's a lot of code. I know there's dynamic objects, but they don't automatically have a way to reference properties by name. What's the easiest way to get and set properties dynamically by name on objects of arbitrary types (ie they have the property but don't all share a common interface or base class)?

**Update:** Upon further research it seems like FastMember, Impromptu, Dynamitey, or maybe FSharp.Dynamic can help here if anyone has any thoughts...

Comment: http://automapper.org/

Comment: @Eser I'm aware of Automapper and use it elsewhere on my project but in this case I need to dynamically fetch properties, make decisions based on the result and then set them. This is a different use case.

Answer (score 4):

At risk of oversimplifying the solution, why not create a pair of extension methods off the object type that abstract the reflection code? Methods like

```
static void SetProperty<T>(this object, string propertyName, T propertyValue) 
static T GetProperty<T>(this object, string propertyName)
```

Usage would be not quite as your question describes:

```
obj2.SetProperty("ArbitraryPropertyName", obj1.GetProperty("AribraryPropertyName");
```

Comment: Well yes...but how is that fundamentally different from reflection? Obviously I wouldn't duplicate the reflection code every time, I'd abstract it to something similar. My question is specifically whats the easiest way of doing this? This isn't exactly a rare use-case don't dynamic objects or another mechanism of c# provide a more modern approach?

Comment: Since I don't have a direct answer, I'm just speculating. But it would seem to me that since we're dealing with strongly typed compiled code, the compiler would need to support the sort of syntax your suggesting. That is, I don't think it exists for C#. The only way that I've performed tasks as you describe has been to use reflection. Since there's bound to be dozens of questions here specifically how to get and set properties with reflection, I presume you are not asking specifically how to use reflection.

Comment: I appreciate it; since this furthers discussion rather than a direct answer, the correct location for it would be in the comment section.

Comment: As for strongly typed code ... yes and no, the DLR is absolutely a thing that is meant in part for these cases. I'm thinking there should be something along the lines of `var foo = new DynamicAccessors(obj); foo["Prop"] = 123`, I simply don't know the correct syntax.